# How to set the display language and alias and make them permanent on Windows cmd

Tags: cmd, command-prompt

I know you can type set `LANG=en_US` to set the language to be American English, and type `doskey np=notepad $*` to set a shortcut np for notepad, but every time I reopen the `cmd`, I have to do these again. How do set once and use forever?

Comment: `Set "LANG=en_US"` doesn't set the language to be American English, it sets a non persistent variable named `LANG` to a string value `en_US`, that's it. If you want to set a persistent variable, _i.e. one which remains after the cmd session has ended_, then take a look at `SetX /?`.

Comment: Thank you very much! What about setting a shortcut for notepad?

Comment: I see no real need, notepad is located in `%PATH%`, just type `notepad` and it opens!